# Python : Writing a dictionary to a csv (short way)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write a dictionary to csv file, but not directly. I put a new field name for dictionary keys.

The following does what I want, but I am wondering if it can be shortened? Especially the last line.

```
import csv

mydict = {"John":{'car':'BMW','age':27}, 'Mike':{'car':'Jetta', 'age':35}}
col_names = ['name','car','age']

with open('junk', 'w' ) as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=col_names)
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, value in mydict.items():
            writer.writerow({'name':key, 'car':value['car'], 'age':value['age']}) #
```

desired output should be:

```
name,car,age
Mike,Jetta,35
John,BMW,27
```

Comment: What is the desired output? Please [edit] your question and include a sample of the CSV.

Comment: This would fit more in code review. Anyway: I don't know that API but taking into account your data source, I would say it is hard to shorten the code.

Comment: @LutzHorn, no need to see the output. The OP states that the output is fine, he only wants to know if the code could be improved.

Comment: Can you change the format of your dictionary? something like {'car':['BMW','Jetta'],'Name':[...],'age':[...]}

Comment: @sachinsaxena Unfortunately I cant

Comment: FWIW, your code looks fine IMHO.

Comment: @AmiTavory True, but in reality mydict has about 20 fileds instead of 2, thus Zac's answer helps a lot.

Comment: That's a good point. You might want to accept his answer, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid repeating field names in the last line you can store data in a temporary dictionary and update it:

```
out = {'name':key}
out.update(value)
writer.writerow(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

`csv` provides `writerows` so something like:

`writer.writerows(dict(mydict[key], name=key) for key in mydict)`

can also be done to minimize the lines of code.

Comment: @EmmetB It should not repeat as it is not much different than what you are doing with loop AFAIK. Also testing in your code snippet it works as expected. You could make a list with the comprehension and use that as well. `[dict(mydict[key], name=key) for key in mydict]`